# How to configure next/link to use different path than basePath

Tags: next.js

The `next/link` component uses the `basePath` defined in the `next.config.js` to generate the URL. Is there a way to configure `next/link` to use a different path than the `basePath`? I want the `basePath` to be different as I want the page to be served on that path but link goes to a different path.